# How can I define a julia macro that defines a macro?

Tags: macros, julia

I would have thought this would work:

```
macro meta_meta(x,y)
  :(macro $x(arg) :($($y) + $arg) end)
end
```

The expected behavior is that calling `@meta_meta(f,2)` should be equivalent to    `macro f(arg) :(2 + $arg) end`

In other words:

```
julia> @meta_meta(f,2)
julia> @f(3)
5
```

Instead I get:

```
ERROR: syntax: invalid macro definition
```

I'm at a bit of a loss for how to proceed. I see that the expression tree for this macro is different from the one I get if I manually generate @f and examine its expression tree, and I've tried several iterations of @meta_meta, but I cannot figure out how to change my definition to get it working.

Comment: Use this as an example: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/def-macro-generator-broken-on-master/1096/3?u=chrisrackauckas . You might be needing to escape something.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! That should do the trick. I'll try that out when I get a chance to figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Macro hygiene is a little finnicky when dealing with a quote inside a quote. Often I find the only way is to refuse macro hygiene entirely, and use `gensym` liberally to simulate it.

However in your reduced example, it's straightforward to just turn the inner quote into an `Expr`:

```
julia> macro meta_meta(x, y)
           :(macro $(esc(x))(arg) Expr(:call, :+, $(esc(y)), esc(arg)) end)
       end
@meta_meta (macro with 1 method)

julia> @meta_meta f 2
@f (macro with 1 method)

julia> @f 3
5
```

If things get more complicated, the approach I mentioned above involves turning off macro hygiene with `esc`. This means that we have to do the hygiene ourself, hence the `gensym`:

```
julia> macro meta_meta(x, y)
           arg = gensym()
           esc(:(macro $x($arg) :($$y + $$arg) end))
       end
@meta_meta (macro with 1 method)

julia> @meta_meta f 2
@f (macro with 1 method)

julia> @f 3
5
```

Comment: Thanks! Chris's comment got me pretty close, but hadn't gotten there yet. I kept running into [this issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/16096). It surprises me that your second solution doesn't run into this problem. I guess if you escape the *entire* expression the bug about escaping arguments doesn't apply.

Comment: @HaberdashPI ah yeah, in my first solution I have initially forgotten to escape arg. However it also doesn't run into that issue; we're not actually escaping any function argument names here. I have updated my answer.